# Improved Query Runtime

Tags: sql-server

The purpose of the query is to give an X tag the probability that a Y tag will also appear.

For example:

Table ListTagsFromPost:

```
id| Tags        |
_________________
1 | <A><B><C><D>|

2 | <A><B>      |

3 | <A><C>      |

4 | <B><D>      |

5 | <A><D>      |

6 | <A><B><C>   |   

7 | <A><C>      |   

8 | <A><D>      |

9 | <B><D>      |
```

The query return :

```
        |A  |   |B|              |C|               |D|
   _____________________________________________________________ 
|A|     |100|   |0.4285714286|   |0.5714285714|   |0.4285714286|

|B|     |0.6|   |100|            |0.4|            |0.6|

|C|     |100|   |0.5|            |100|            |0.25|

|D|     |0.6|   |0.6|            |0.2|            |100|
```

The problem is that I have 50,000 records per table ListTagsFromPost.

That means there can be lots of tags (as in example A, B, C, D)
Need a simple query in order to get the result

Comment: Can you take the time to format your data into a readable format please? Also, in your first table, I'm not sure if those are a variable amount of columns or delimited data. if the latter, then you should really be changing your design. Storing delimited data only makes things harder. If you have a many to one relationship you should be designing your data with that in mind by using multiple tables.

Comment: what's purpose of `left join [bgroup72_prod].[dbo].[Tags] as T2 on T1.TagName!=T2.TagName` why did you use `!=` , did you try to kill your performance? :)